# Unable to reach watchdog.servicebus.appfabriclabs.com

Tags: azure, appfabric

I'm deploying a few Azure services to the Cloud and they fail with the following error, "Unable to reach watchdog.servicebus.appfabriclabs.com" when tryng to connect to the ServiceBus.

When I ping this host the address cannot be resolved. However, when I ping watchdog.servicebus.windows.net this is resolved.

Is there an explicit way to make my services use watchdog.servicebus.windows.net instead? Something wrong with my subscription maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to using the CTP/Labs version of the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll. For Azure production environment you should be using version 1.0, 1.5 or 1.6 corresponding to Azure SDK versions. It appears that you have a version that is targets the LABS environment and may be versioned 2.0/99 etc. 
You can obtain the latest ServiceBus client dll from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) or downloading the [Azure SDK](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/). Another thing to check for is if you have any servicebus.config file in .NET config directories that may be pointing to the LABS environment, more details on that are [here](http://abhishekrlal.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/clientsdkconfig/).

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. That's spot on. I switched to v1.5 and got rid of the error.